# i18n and modules retrieves from wrong path in Yii2

Tags: php, internationalization, yii2

I don't know if this is a bug or a mistake on my end but basically I followed the Yii2 documentation to setup i18n translations for modules. The following snippet is directly copy pasted from the Yii2 guide.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $this->registerTranslations();
}

public function registerTranslations()
{
    Yii::$app->i18n->translations['modules/users/*'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
        'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
        'basePath' => '@app/modules/users/messages',
    ];
}

public static function t($category, $message, $params = [], $language = null)
{
    return Yii::t('modules/users/' . $category, $message, $params, $language);
}
```

According to the guide I should call it like this:

```
Module::t('validation', 'your custom validation message')
```

However, Yii2 tries to load the the 'validation.php' from the wrong location. This is the output of the debugger:

```
The message file for category 'modules/users/validation' does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.../domains/localhost/public_html/.../backend/modules/users/messages/en/modules/users/validation.php
```

From what I understand, it should be looking for `modules/users/message/<lang>/validation.php` instead, which makes a lot more sense than what it is looking for right now.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply add a [`filemap`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-phpmessagesource.html#$fileMap-detail) param, e.g. :

```
public function registerTranslations()
{
    Yii::$app->i18n->translations['modules/users/*'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
        'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
        'basePath' => '@app/modules/users/messages',
        'fileMap' => [
            'modules/users/validation' => 'validation.php',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#translating-module-messages

**EDIT** : As stated in Yii2 guide, if you want to remove `filemap`, your `validation.php` file should be in **modules/users/messages/[lang]/modules/users/validation.php**.

> Instead of configuring fileMap you can rely on convention which is to use the category name as the file name (e.g. category app/error will result in the file name app/error.php under the basePath.

Comment: That works. A little confusing as the guide states:

Instead of using fileMap you can simply use convention of category mapping to the same named file and use Module::t('validation', 'your custom validation message') or Module::t('form', 'some form label') directly.